# PostgreSQL Trigger on last deleted line

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-delete, postgresql-triggers

I created a trigger that updates the number of species counted from the "effectif" table to the "citation" table.
It works well except when I delete the last row, the calculation does not perform and remains at the last state. For example, if I delete the last row on the "effectif" table that represents 6 species, I would still have 6 on my "citation" table where I'm suppose to find 0 or null.
Here is my trigger :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data.del_eff_tot()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
IF OLD.effectif IS NOT NULL THEN
UPDATE data.citation
SET effectif =
(SELECT sum(a.effectif) FROM data.effectif a, data.citation b WHERE OLD.id_cit = a.id_cit AND OLD.id_cit = b.id)+COALESCE((SELECT a.effectif FROM data.effectif a, data.citation b WHERE OLD.id_cit = a.id_cit AND OLD.id_cit = b.id AND sexe = 'sexe_4_1'),0)
WHERE id IN (SELECT id_cit FROM data.effectif a, data.citation b WHERE OLD.id_cit = b.id AND b.id = a.id_cit);
END IF;
RETURN OLD;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION data.del_eff_tot()
  OWNER TO postgres;

------------------------------

CREATE TRIGGER del_eff_tot
  AFTER DELETE
  ON data.effectif
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE data.del_eff_tot();
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and table structure in question

Comment: Change the trigger to `BEFORE DELETE`.  An `AFTER TRIGGER` happens after the `DELETE` has completed and there is nothing to count, therefore the 0.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

By using BEFORE, I get the same problem. I have the impression that it performs the calculation with the value before deleting it.

By using AFTER, the WHERE condition I have the impression that the calculation is good but doesn't match any more with any lines and therefore doesn't UPDATE anything.

Comment: My two tables :
CREATE TABLE data.effectif
(
  integrated workforce,
  id_cit integer,
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('data.detail_effective_id_seq'::regclass),
  sex character varying,
  stage character varying,
  prec_stade character varying,
  CONSTRAINT detail_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINED positive eff_positive CHECK (effective >= 0)
)

Comment: CREATE TABLE data.citation
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('data.citation_id_seq'::regclass),
  sp_typing character varying(250),
  integrated workforce,
  id_inv integer,
  id_taxo integer,
  confidential boolean,
  prec_eff character varying(80),
  sensibility character varying(80),
  mode_contact character varying(80),
  CONSTRAINED quote_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINED positive eff_positive CHECK (effective >= 0)
)